# How do I pass data from parent application to child application Mac Os X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an Mac application which checks for a version update everytime it is launched. Now if the there is new version on the server, this Mac application launches another application called the "Updater". Now I want to pass data from the Mac application to the Updater (e.g. parent pid, link to a file on the server)

Any suggestions as to how I can do that.

Comment: Why not integrate the updater into the original application?

Comment: If you have your heart set on making it a separate application, just run the "Check for updates" code in the updater and get the info that you want to pass there, rather than trying to pass it to a separate application.

Comment: The original application is written in C++/Qt. The updater is purely native. So have to invoke the updater and pass it some data. I am able to invoke the updater but just not sure how to pass data.

Comment: How are you invoking the updater? Share that code.

Comment: I cannot add the "check for updates" inside the updater because the original application is written in C++/QT and is made to run on both windows and MAC Os X. We cannot change code that is common the both. So the norm is that check for updates happens in the original application and then based on differences the updater is invoked.

Comment: If you're using Objective-C and Cocoa, have a look at `NSTask`, `NSPipe`, and `NSFileHandle`.  They don't do anything magical, but they do simplify things a bit. "Building Cocoa Applications" by Garfinkel & Mahoney have a chapter that illustrates in detail how to do it.